# Fixed-point notation is not behaving acording to the documentation

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I want to format some values with a fixed precision of 3 unless it's an integer. In that case I don't want any decimal point or trailing 0s.

Acording to the docs, the 'f' type in string formating should remove the decimal point if no digits follow it:

> If no digits follow the decimal point, the decimal point is also removed unless the # option is used.

But testing it with python3.8 I get the following results:

```
>>> f'{123:.3f}'
'123.000'
>>> f'{123.0:.3f}'
'123.000'
```

Am I misunderstanding something? How could I achive the desired result without using if else checks?

Comment: Both your examples *do* have digits following the decimal point.

Comment: how does 123 has following digits after the decimal point?

Comment: The docs talk about the `.3f` part, not the value that is being formatted. That's 3 digits. Use `.0f` and the decimal point will disappear from your output. I am afraid to achieve what you want, you'd have to be more verbose and type-check.

Comment: Because you asked for three digits after the decimal point. Compare `.0f` and `#.0f`.

Comment: oh I see now, thanks for the explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to forcefully achieve both your desired outputs with the same f-string expression, you could apply some kung-fu like

```
i = 123
f"{i:.{3*isinstance(i, float)}f}"
# '123'

i = 123.0
f"{i:.{3*isinstance(i, float)}f}"
# '123.000'
```

But this won't improve your code in terms of readability. There's no harm in being more explicit.

Comment: That's a clever way to achieve what I want. But yeah, I agree with you about readability. I will take your advise and use an explicit method.